# Using postMessage across different namespaced components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

In Salesforce, postMessage is mainly used for communicating in between Visualforce and Lightning components

- [Communicating between Lightning Components and Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html)

**[Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)**

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin
>   communication between Window objects

The description and intent of this is quite clear, however, if we use it to send/receive data across components belonging to different namespaces (with api v40+ = Locker Service), for example:

> `c:cmp1` and `namespace:cmp2`

because, the namespaced component does not provide any event to do so natively within lightning (using app or cmp events) but does provide the capability of attaching a script (where  this can be implemented easily), would using postMessage be a convenient and secure approach?

If not - is there a better way to communicate in between components that bellong to different namespaces without native lightning events?

Comment: No, postMessage wouldn't technically be appropriate here. Ideally, the managed package owner should fix the component.

Comment: Pardon my dumb question. I'm confused about what exactly you're asking ?, But Let's say if `namespace:cmp2` raised an Application event your `c:cmp1` should be able to handle it as long as you know the what are the params you need look for. There is no need for `postMessage` here.

Comment: thats the thing - there is no applicatiton event or whatsoever - so -  essentially, the only thing I can think of  was using a postMessage, at least while the managed package does any changes to their components. In  essence, asking what is the downside of using postMessage

Comment: Ah got you now. Like @sfdcfox mentioned package owner has to fix it rather than using `postMessage`!

Comment: If the namespaced component say updates a record or you can update a record by the capability of the script that you can attach, one approach I can think of is to write a trigger on that particular object to raise a platform event, and then subscribe it in your custom component?

Comment: the script is mostly used to interact with framework events, its a 3rd party library. these events sometimes need to wait for something from the top level component which does not belong to the namespace. newer components of this package have was to do so, but older components dont, hence the postMessage